# NIntegrate failed to converge, how to handle two variable numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration

```
N0 = 1000;
N1 = 0.1 N0;

s = 0.1; 
T1 = N0/1000;

NtStep[t_, T_] := 
 Piecewise[{{N0, t < T1}, {N1, T1 <= t <= (T1 + T)}, {N0, t > T}}]

Tvalues = Range[0, N0/5, N0/1000];



Pfix[t0_, T_] := 
 1. - Exp[-4/
   NIntegrate[
    E^(-s (t - t0)) (2 NtStep[t0, T])/NtStep[t, T], {t, t0, N0}]]


pfmine = 
 Table[1/(N0 - Log[N0 s 0.5]/(0.5 s))
    NIntegrate[
    Pfix[t0, T], {t0, 0, N0 (*- (Log[N0 s 0.5]/(0.5 s))*)}], {T, 0, 
   N0/5, N0/1000}]

Pfixotto[t0_, T_] := 2/(
 NtStep[t0, T] NIntegrate[ 
   E^(- s (t - t0)) 1/NtStep[t, T], {t, t0, N0}])

pfotto = 
 Table[1/(N0 - Log[N0 s 0.5]/(0.5 s))
    NIntegrate[
    Pfixotto[t0, T], {t0, 0, N0 (*- (Log[N0 s 0.5]/(0.5 s))*)}], {T, 
   0, N0/5, N0/1000}]


customTicksX = {{1/N0 2  \[Pi], 
    Row[{"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(2  \[Pi]\), SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(0\)]]\
\) "}]}, {1/N0 100  \[Pi], 
    Row[{"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(100  \[Pi]\), SubscriptBox[\(N\), \
\(0\)]]\)"}]}, {1/N0 25  \[Pi], 
    Row[{"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(25  \[Pi]\), SubscriptBox[\(N\), \
\(0\)]]\)"}]}, {1/N0 400  \[Pi], 
    Row[{"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(400\\\ \[Pi]\), SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(0\
\)]]\)"}]}};

a = ListPlot[Transpose@{Tvalues, pfmine}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> All , FrameLabel -> {"growth rate", "Pfix"}, 
   Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], 
   Frame -> Thickness[0.003]];

b = ListPlot[Transpose@{Tvalues, pfotto}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"growth rate", "Pfix"}, 
   Frame -> True, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium], 
   Frame -> Thickness[0.003]];
Show[a, b]
```

I am not able to run the above code and get error as
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please explain what your code is doing and where exactly you encounter an issue.

Comment: I have edited the code and pasted the error which I get

Comment: Executing `pfmine = 
 Table[1/(N0 - Log[N0 s 0.5]/(0.5 s))
    NIntegrate[
    Pfix[t0, T], {t0, 0, N0 (*- (Log[N0 s 0.5]/(0.5 s))*)}], {T, 0, 
   N0/5, N0/1000}]`, I obtain an error  "NIntegrate::nlim: t = t0 is not a valid limit of integration.".

Comment: @user64494 yes, I think you may ignore this error because t0 is a variable whose value is assigned later

Comment: There are other errors there, for example, "NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in t0 near {t0} = {4.84544}. NIntegrate obtained 186.19850829351896` and 0.04665384952817386` for the integral and error estimates.".

Comment: @user64494 Yes, I don't know how to resolve these errors.

Comment: @SachinKaushik Reduce accuracy warning threshold by `SetOptions[NIntegrate, AccuracyGoal -> 1, PrecisionGoal -> 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem consists in the behavior if NIntegrate. Consider:

```
Clear[f];
f[x_] := NIntegrate[t, {t, x, 10}]
NIntegrate[f[z], {z, 0, 1 }]
```

This gives error messages:

`NIntegrate::nlim: t = z is not a valid limit of integration`.

NIntgrate tries to simplify its argument f[z], that is symbolic,  and obviously fails. To prevent this you need to ensure that f[z] is only evaluated if z is numeric. You can due this e.g. by:

```
Clear[f];
f[x_?NumericQ] := (NIntegrate[t, {t, 1, 10}])
NIntegrate[f[z], {z, 0, 1 }]
```

Now there are no more error messages.

Applied to your code,you have this problem with: Pfix[t0_, T_]. Therefore define:

```
Pfix[t0_?NumericQ, T_] := 
 1. - Exp[-4/
    NIntegrate[
     E^(-s  (t - t0))  (2  NtStep[t0, T])/NtStep[t, T], {t, t0, N0}]]
```

Further, you have convergence problems in the integral in "pfmine" that may or may not give an inaccurate result. But I will not investigate this now.

Comment: perfect!
thank you